# Which programming site do I post my question on?

Tags: discussion, scope, site-recommendation

Scenario: I have a (semi) working server application that is being field tested right now with 2 clients. It's freezing every couple days, due to running out of memory (I think). I need to do optimization, and make sure it's scalable and can handle up to a couple hundred of clients.

I know my question doesn't belong on Programmers since it's no longer a concept and it is in the form of code. Way past the whiteboard stage.

I don't think it belongs on Code Review, since it's not working 100% as intended - At the same time, I don't think it fully belongs on SO either, since it's not a real "error" situation where I can post a stacktrace (since there isn't one).

I also can't sit in front of the server and debug it while the clients are testing it due to time zone differences (office is closed while the clients are on the other side of the world). I have some log files, but no errors are present in them. I'm also pretty sure I know why the server is going out of memory.

I know this may sound like a duplicate, but it really isn't - I've read 5 or 6 meta questions on which programming site to use already, none of which helped me place my question. Where do I put my question?

Edit: The server works for some time before suddenly freezing up. I'm looking to ask why my code suddenly <strike>bursts into flames</strike> dies, or how to implement an optimization of said code - perhaps there was a logical flaw in the way I'm dealing with my threads, perhaps it's some obscure bug that no one knows about, but at this point in time, I've only been able to isolate the problem to a specific aspect of my code.

Comment: If you had posted this as a question on StackOverflow, I would have told you to set up a process to log the memory utilization of the process during the times when you are not there, so you can confirm or reject your hypothesis.

Comment: What would you ask?  For strategies to fix this?  Or for possible fixes?  The first is a bit listy, the second is probably impossible to answer and thus becomes a list of guesses.  You need to brew up some coffee and work on it no matter the time zone.  Don't try to use SE as a substitute for that.  Also, better logging always helps.  It's trivial to log memory consumption on a server.  Do so.  You just seem to have not done enough work at this stage to ask a decent answerable question.

Comment: @Will I'd most likely be asking for method of optimization or to see why my code breaks after several days. I'll implement the memory consumption logging, but I'm 99% sure it has to do with my thread management. I have some commands programmed into the server that I ran just before it crashed about a week ago, and it showed an absurd number of threads (172) for only 2 clients. The server had been running for 2 weeks continuously before the issue came up. The logs show that my thread management was working fine at first but suddenly stopped working.

Comment: @Aify You're managing your own threads? That sounds like fun. Start there.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I shouldn't be? I'm not sure I understand what the implication of your comment is

Comment: @Aify It all depends on your backend; but unless you have a clear reason to, stay away from multithreaded code; it's fraught with peril and is overused. again, we don't know which that is; but it'd take too much time/writing to fill us in to the level we'd need to be to understand whether that was a good idea or not (another reason why at this Juncture, your question is too broad for Stack Overflow).

Comment: Thanks for posting this here by the way!

Comment: Putting this here was definitely a much better idea than asking it on another SE site - just the comments have helped me quite a bit, and brought up some important issues for me. @enderland thanks! I strongly believe in asking for any scenario where clarification is required, and this is definitely one of those situations where asking was the best thing to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With what you have posted, I don't think your question would be a good fit on any SE sites for now.

As @Will mentionned in the comments, the next logical step for you would be to find a way to debug your application and get your hands on the actual error that makes your code burst into flames.

Google might help you find some debugging tricks, I know it did help me in the past. If you have colleagues that can help you, a fresh pair of eyes can surely help you more that SO would in your current situation. Otherwise, you need to start isolating your problem, and ideally reproduce it in a controlled environment so you can fix and test your code before pushing your changes.